# About the partial derivative of a composite function $u =f(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f$ be any smooth function of the 2-sphere $S^2$ and take $g:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb S^2$, $g(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$. Consider $f\circ g$.

How can I expand the expression:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f\circ g)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\Big\{f(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})\Big\}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming $f:\Bbb{S}^2\to\mathbb R$.
$$\boldsymbol{g}(x_1,x_2)=\left(x_1,x_2,\sqrt{1-{x_1}^2-{x_2}^2}\right)$$
I've used the bold font to emphasize $\boldsymbol g$ is vector valued. Now, let $F=f\circ \boldsymbol g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb R$.
$$\nabla F=\nabla(f\circ \boldsymbol{g})=(\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol g)((\nabla f)\circ\boldsymbol g)$$
Using the chain rule. I'll leave it as an exercise to show
$$\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol g=2$$
Hence
$$(\nabla F)(x_1,x_2)=2(\nabla f)\left(x_1,x_2,\sqrt{1-{x_1}^2-{x_2}^2}\right)$$
Finally,
$$(\partial_1F)(x_1,x_2)=(\nabla F)_1(x_1,x_2)=2(\partial_1 f)\left(x_1,x_2,\sqrt{1-{x_1}^2-{x_2}^2}\right)$$
Here $\partial_i$ is the partial derivative w.r.t the $i$th argument.

Comment: The chain rule is $\nabla (f\circ\vec g)=(\nabla\vec g)\times((\nabla f)\circ\vec g)$

Answer (score 0):

When $\vec g(x,y)=\langle x, y, h(x,y)\rangle$ then applying the chain rule gives:

$$\partial_1(f\circ\vec g)(x,y)=(\partial_1f\circ\vec g+\partial_1h\cdot(\partial_3f\circ\vec g))(x,y)$$

Or$$\dfrac{\partial (f\circ\vec g)(x,y)}{\partial x}=\left.\dfrac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}\right\vert_{z=h(x,y)}+\dfrac{\partial h(x,y)}{\partial x}\cdot\left.\dfrac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial z}\right\vert_{z=h(x,y)}$$

---

Alternatively:

$$\def\p{\partial}\begin{align}\nabla(f\circ\vec g)&=\nabla\vec g{\times}((\nabla f)\circ\vec g)\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\p_1g_1&\p_1g_2&\p_1g_3\\\p_2g_1&\p_2g_2&\p_2g_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\p_1f\\\p_2f\\\p_3f\end{bmatrix}\circ\vec g\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\p_xx&\p_xy&\p_x\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2)}\\\p_yx&\p_yy& \p_y\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2)}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\p_1f\\\p_2f\\\p_3f\end{bmatrix}\circ\langle x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2)}\rangle\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\p_1f-\dfrac{x~\p_3f}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\\\p_2f-\dfrac{y~\p_3f}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\end{bmatrix}\circ\langle x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\rangle\end{align}$$